# Liquibase failed to add not null, unique, current timestamp on MySQL

Tags: mysql, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm teaching myself how to use Liquibase for MySQL database versioning and migrations.

I'm on a Spring Boot project with Maven and MySQL for handling databases.

I created a master changelog for including several changelogs file, until this point it's all good. The problem start when applying my first migration creating a simple user table with id, email, name, created and updated columns.

The migrations runs well except for one thing. Liquibase is not applying the NOT NULL for all the columns, the TIMESTAMP data type for updated nor the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP extra, and also is ignoring the unique index for the email column.

My first try was on a .xml changelog, I thought it could be the .xml format so I change it for a SQL syntax. That didn't work either. I also created the table first and later add the not null constraint and didn't work.

At this point I don't know what else to do and I can't find any more good post or documentation about it.

Note: The only "special" constraint it's applying is the primary key and auto increment and ignore all the others features.

I would be very greatful for any help I can get!

Here's my liquibase.properties:

```
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/skullproject
username = skull
password = skullpass
driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Here's my migration XML changelog:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="f6rnando">
    <createTable tableName="user">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="email" type="VARCHAR(80)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="password" type="VARCHAR(80)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(80)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="updated" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="created" type="DATETIME">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="f6rnando" id="1491156436761-3">
    <addUniqueConstraint columnNames="email"
        constraintName="email_UNIQUE" tableName="user" />
</changeSet>
```

And here's my MySQL changelog:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset f6rnando:1
CREATE TABLE user (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
  created DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE INDEX email_UNIQUE (email ASC)
);

--changeset f6rnando:2
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL;

--changeset f6rnando:3
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY password VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL;
```

After all the ways I've tried, this is always the same result:
[MySQL Table info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtXxP.png)

I ran the CREATE TABLE statement on MySQL Workbench and got no problem at all. All the constraints where created just fine:
[MySQL Table executed on Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnJUO.png)

Comment: Why are you bothering with all that XML? Just use `alter` statements as raw SQL in your liquibase update. That's what I have always done.

Comment: I did the SQL ALTER as I described up there in the post, once I realiced Liquibase failed to apply the constraints I changed to SQL, but got the same result. Somehow Liquibase doesn't apply the NOT NULL, the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, the UNIQUE INDEX. Either in XML or SQL.

Comment: This is not a liquibase problem. It's an SQL problem. Get the alter working at the command line first. Then liquibase will work. If necessary, separate the commands into separate updates. See [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: I grabed the SQL CREATE statement from the post and ran it on MySQL Workbench and got no problem. There was no need for running the ALTER statements because the CREATE TABLE worked out how it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

After a week of research and trials, the problem was a Hibernate configuration. In my `application.properties` file I had `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop` which means according to the `@Entity` classes, the database is created then dropped when the `SessionFactory` closes. Apparently this overrides the Liquibase behavior.

To solve this problem I set the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none`. Then Liquibase was able to behave as expected.